# Applet method calling from Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, security, applet

I have an applet to upload some files from specific folder and delete them,but something is wrong when I call an applet function from my javascript code, when I call that function from `init()` it works fine.

My applet code :

```
public class Uploader extends Applet {
   String serverPath;
   String clientPath;
   private JSObject win;
   @Override
   public void init() {
       serverPath = getParameter("serverPath");
       clientPath = getParameter("clientPath");
       try {
           win = JSObject.getWindow(this);
       } catch (JSException e) {
           log.warning("Can't access JSObject object");
       }
       upload(topic,clientPath);
   }
   public void upload(String topic,String clientPath) {
       log.log(Level.SEVERE, "upload functiond");
       DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
       MultipartEntity form = new MultipartEntity();
       log.log(Level.SEVERE, "upload functiond2");
       try {
            File directory = new File(clientPath);
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "upload functiond2.2");
            File[] files = directory.listFiles();
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "upload functiond2.5");
            int i = 0;
            for (File file : files) {
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "upload functiond2.6");
                i++;
                form.addPart("file" + String.valueOf(i), new FileBody(file));
                System.out.println("adding file " + String.valueOf(i) + " " + file);
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "adding file " + String.valueOf(i) + " " + file);
            }
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "upload functiond3");
            form.addPart("topic", new StringBody(topic, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            form.addPart("action", new StringBody(action, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            form.addPart("path", new StringBody(serverPath, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(serverPath);
      ....
```

and this is my javascript code:

```
document.applet.upload(title,"c:\scan");
```

When I called from javascript only log printed:

```
log.log(Level.SEVERE, "upload functiond2.2");
```

Note that when I call from `init` method of applet it works fine.

I wrap my code into a `PriviligedAction`, but  goes only one step forward and hang on

```
log.log(Level.SEVERE, "upload functiond2.5");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interaction of Java and JS complicates security.  The JRE cannot trust the JS, so it decides the entire 'chain of operations' that include your code is untrusted.  There is a way to fix it.

The code needs to be wrapped in a [`PrivilegedAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/PrivilegedAction.html) and called using one of the [`AccessController` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#method_summary) that `doPrivileged(..)`.  Look at the top of the `AccessController` docs. (above the methods) to see example usage.

Comment: when I add PrivilagedAction it goes to log.log(Level.SEVERE, "upload functiond2.5");  one step forward,and nothing else.can you help me again?

Comment: I suggest you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  I am especially interested in what happens in that `catch` that is implied by `...`.  Make sure it includes an `e.printStackTrace();` or similar and get the output in the Java Console (to copy/paste here).  BTW  Most of those log messages should be around `Level.INFO`

Comment: yes,that was a null pointer exception which i could not see,after adding annotation @SuppressWarnings("serial") before my applet class ,exception comes to console.   thank you.

Comment: Ignore exception output at your peril! ;)  Glad you got it sorted. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson my question marked as duplicate by you ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048078/ ) and i came here to thank you ;) i worked for me too.