# Signed Applet - File dialog fails to open on any but local client

Tags: java, javascript, security, applet, signed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [applet method calling from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361369/applet-method-calling-from-javascript)

This is a persistent problem for me.  I have tested locally a signed applet in a Tomcat deployment that allows local file access.  I can open the file dialog box and create files locally on the same box that is deploying the application and client to the application.  Therein may be my problem, but I thought, not up to now, on any other client it fails to open the dialog box even though those client have fully accepted the certificates and granted all rights, and disabled verification(just to get it working tighten later).

Why cant any connecting client open the local file dialog box?  Is it a need for a security policy on that local PC?(running Java6).  I thought with signed applets local policy files were not necessary.  Is this even possible over a TC deployment?  I very much need this answered and educated.  Thank you.

Comment: 1) Where can we see the applet? 2) Does JS interact with the applet? -- Signing the applet should be enough, but there is also a possible alternative in the [file service of the JNP API](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

Comment: @A Yes, javascript is interacting with the applet.  Can I have that structure and still open filedialog on attached non server clients?  Below is js
<pre>            function readFile(){
        dialog.show();
        var zippedFile = document.probe.ccAuth13_openFile(true,null);  
        var numOfFiles = document.probe.ccAuth19_readZip(zippedFile);
        log.debug('number of Files in zip = '+numOfFiles);
        dialog.hide();
}<code?

Comment: For code samples, [edit them into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14573095/edit) and use code formatting rather than squash them into a comment.  As to applets+security+JS, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12361407/418556).

Comment: @a It worked perfectly.  Is it possible to restrict the restrict the permissions further?  I know a priori the names of the files I will create.  Can I restrict the read,write,delete to only those files?  Also how do I accept your answer?

Comment: You cannot accept a comment as an answer.  Feel free to up-vote the answer to the duplicate question though.  ;)  As to how you would limit the choices, I would add some sanity checks within the applet code.  If the file name does not match one of those you are expecting, pop a message to the user and stop processing.