# How to solve java.security.AccessControlException?

Tags: java, security, applet, accesscontrolexception, tempdir

I am trying to access client's temp directory through my applet on my web project.
When I run the applet by itself, it gets the `tempdir` with no problem.

When I try to get it on my project using javascript and calling the applet method, I am having `accessControlException` on my javascript console. Also I am getting the same exception when I try to read a file under the temp directory.

This is what I see exactly:

```
java.security.accesscontrolexception access denied (java.util.propertypermission java.io.tmpdir read)
java.security.accesscontrolexception access denied (java.io.filepermission read)
```

How to solve `java.security.AccessControlException`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applet method calling from Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361369/applet-method-calling-from-javascript).  Of course, this applet also needs to be digitally signed & trusted, as is implied by 4 out of 5 of SO questions involving 'applet+accesscontrolexception'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution is just to sign the applet.

Comment: Not enough when JS is in the mix.

Comment: Thanks, but signing the applet was not the only thing that I had to do. I also needed to use AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
     public Object run() { }  }); method wherever i needed to access a file or system property.