# How to deploy JavaFX + JPA Persistence (JSE) inside web browser (not web start)?

Tags: java, web-services, jpa, javafx-8

I have deployed a java hello world "inside a browser" on http://www.applesweet.net/home.htm just to show that things are working fine. You can try it by just typing the url. The package is built using Netbeans.

Therefore, I try to deploy something more complicated using the same method. It's actually a client application I developed with JSE(1.8) + JavaFX8 + Persistence(Eclipse lib). You can try it with this link http://www.applesweet.net/dist/ProjCostTracking.html.  It gives me the following error in the Java console.

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "eclipselink.persistencexml" "read")
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.plugin2.applet.FXAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.findPersistenceArchives(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:275)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfoInArchives(JPAInitializer.java:150)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfo(JPAInitializer.java:135)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
>       at ProjCostTracking.KYdb.getEntityManagerFactory(KYdb.java:69)
>       at ProjCostTracking.KYdb.(KYdb.java:31)
>       at ProjCostTracking.Main.start(Main.java:161)
>       at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The code is here:
[image]

I have tried to hard coded the username, password, ip address and port. The application runs fine as a standalone application.

I am aware of the file persistence.xml must be accessible. I am aware that the persistence.xml is already inside the JAR file. However, I sort of put it everywhere I can; under WEB-INF or along side with the JAR file and even inside LIB folder just in case.

[image]

The following snapshot shows how my files are deployed on the Godaddy web hosting service.

[image: FTP Path]

It's more like likely related to JPA...but I just can't figure it out. It is working fine as a standalone application.

Any suggestion is welcomed, thanks for the guidance. :)

Comment: I would imagine that that the default permissions of a JVM hosted within a browser would be much more restrictive than a JVM hosted in the OS itself?  If this is an applet, would signing the applet provide it more permissions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650010/how-to-solve-java-security-accesscontrolexception

Comment: What EdH said might be true, also I am  a little rusty on JPA, but I don't think the browser/applet allows direct communication to a database. Probably need a webservice somewhere in between.