# access applet method from java script not working in 1.5

Tags: java, applet, java-5

We have a code that access Java applet public methods in JavaScript. This is working fine in browser using 1.7 and 1.6 JREs but failing with 1.5 JRE. Tried checking if accessing java applet method from JavaScript is not supported in 1.5, couldn't find any reference.

Does this approach works in 1.5 JRE?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this approach works in 1.5 JRE?

I'm pretty sure I've seen it work in every major Java version since 1.3.

- Does the code use [`AccessController`/`doPrivileged`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12361407/418556)?
- Does the HTML declare `scriptable='true'`?