# Java blocking applet exécution : access denied

Tags: java, jar, applet, illegalargumentexception, jarsigner

I'm facing a problem when executing code that is part of an applet loaded in my browser. The jar file is generated via a maven build and then I signed the jar with the following command :

```
jarsigner -keystore MYKEYSTORE -storepass mykeystorepass -keypass mypass library.jar MYALIAS
```

I activated my Java console when executing the applet. The applet is well launched but when I click on a button that call some piece of code in my applet, I'm getting the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not access public package.DataHolder() 
    (from class package.DataHolder; failed to set access: access denied 
    ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")**
```

Comment: *"If anyone already encountered the problem and found a solution."* ..what? What is it the reader supposed to do if they have already 'found a solution'? BTW - I'm surprised you managed to get an applet loaded in a browser in this day and age!See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). BTW - is Maven generating a 'self signed' app.? Even more surprising it loads..

Comment: My company just got the maintenance for this application running under Firefox 31 ESR because yes applet aren't supported after Firefox 45 ESR.
The applet is not self-signed by maven. The client gave me certificates and generetad a keystore and I'm signing the applet in command line as I explained in my question.

Comment: *"The applet is well launched but when I click on a button that call some piece of code in my applet,"* So.. is JavaScript involved in this somehow?

Comment: Yes the application is implemented in GWT

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12361407/418556) solves the problem.

Comment: I enclosed the method which is throwing an exception in a AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction() {} block but I still get the same error.

Comment: Create a [mcve] of code that fails.

Comment: After some investigation I just realized that the problem is only happening when I'm launching the application locally.
On a distant server the application is working well.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations I "solved" the problem by adding permissions into the JVM. This may be done more properly in the code but I needed to solve my problem quickly.
Edit the file into java.policy in the JVM by adding all the needed permissions as follow :

```
grant {
   permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
};
```